# How to test an install or first launch of an Android application

Tags: android, android-testing

I'm developing an Android application and I want to test the first launch, i.e., install, of the app.

I'm currently using an ApplicationTestCase and a hardware device. However, I always have to delete the app from my device before re-running the test. Additionally, the `onCreate()` method of the application class is called before the first test-method. Hence, giving me a hard time to verify actions of the first call.

Is there an approach that avoids these issues?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could have the onCreate() method test for a specific property in the app's preferences, to determine if this is the first call. Something like this:

```
final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
if (settings.getBoolean("first_start", true)) {
    //first start

    settings.edit().putBoolean("first_start", false).commit(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm doing something similar right now. However, my problem is that I add different properties to the shared preferences depending on the user. I would like to verify these settings in every test run but I don't want to de-install the app every time from the device.